# sequence multiplication limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Need help with the following question :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of limit, we have for all $n>N$, $a_nb_n > 1-\epsilon$ but since $a_n\leq 1\implies a_n b_n\leq b_n$ then $b_n > 1-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, which is just the definition of $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(b_n) = 1$. By symmetry we get the same result for $a_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is wrong, growth isn't relevant here.

Let $a_n=1-\dfrac{|\sin n|}n$ and $b_n=1-\dfrac{|\cos n|}n$.

Neither $a_n$ nor $b_n$ nor $a_n\cdot b_n$ are growing sequences, yet they remain in range $[0,1]$, and they tend to $1$.

Comment: You are right, thank you for the example